# ¿Cual es la manera correcta de enviar varios conjunto de datos en el response usando Nodejs y mssql?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, nodejs, express, asincronismo

Buenas a todos,
Tengo una aplicación web hecha en Nodejs, en una de las peticiones debo de enviar dos conjuntos de datos, los cuales se recuperan independientemente de una base de datos Microsfot SQL Server.Mi consulta es la siguiente ¿Esta es la manera correcta?

```
function getUsers (req, res) {
  User.findUser(null, null, null, (recordSet) => {
   let users = recordSet[0]
   Rol.findRol(null, null, (recordSet) => {
      let roles = recordSet[0]
      return res.status(200).render('users', {
        users: users, roles: roles
      })
   })
  })
}
```

¿Y si debiera enviar un tercer conjunto lo debería introducir dentro del callback de la llamada a la funcion findRol?

Agradezco su apoyo, les dejo el codigo de los modelos User y Rol

Modelo Rol

```
'use strict'
const sql = require('mssql')
const db = require('../models/db')

function findRol (rolId = null, active = null, callback) {
  db.sendRequest((cp) => {
    new sql.Request(cp)
   .input('rolid', rolId)
   .input('active', active)
   .execute('crmFindRol')
   .then((recordSet) => {
      callback(recordSet)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
   })
 })
}

module.exports = {
  findRol
}
```

Modelo User

```
'use strict'

const sql = require('mssql')
const db = require('../models/db')

function findUser (userName = null, userId = null, active = null, callback) {
  db.sendRequest((cp) => {
    new sql.Request(cp)
    .input('username', userName)
    .input('userid', userId)
    .input('active', active)
    .execute('crmFindUser')
    .then((recordSet) => {
      console.log(recordSet)
      callback(recordSet)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
  })
}

module.exports = {
  findUser
}
```

Y este es el archivo db.js

```
'use strict'

const sql = require('mssql')
const config = require('../config')
const sqlConnection = `mssql://${config.user}:${config.password}@${config.host}/${config.db}`

function sqlConnect () {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    sql.connect(sqlConnection).then(() => {
      console.log(`Se estableció exitosamente conexión con la base de datos`)
      resolve(null)
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.error(`Error al conectar a la base de datos: ${err}`)
    })
  })
}

function sendRequest (request) {
  request(sqlConnection)
}

module.exports = {
  sqlConnect: sqlConnect,
  sendRequest: sendRequest
}
```

Comment: Es correcto. Siempre la respuesta debe enviarse en el último callback o promesa.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la pregunta es algo antigua creo que la motivación es interesante, así que voy a dejar esta respuesta por si alguien llega a esta página buscando una respuesta.

Tal y cómo has definido Rol y User lo que comentas es correcto. Cada operación debe de hacerse en un nuevo callback anidado ya que son operaciones asíncronas.

Una manera de evitar tanto anidamiento en el código es extrayendo el código de las funciones. Por ejemplo:

```
function getUsers (req, res) {
    const sendResult = function (users, roles) {
        res.status(200).render('users', { users, roles });
    }

    const findUserCallback = function (recordSet) {
        const users = recordSet[0];

        const findRolCallback = function (recordSet) {
            const roles = recordSet[0];
            sendResult(users, roles);
        }

        Rol.findRol(null, null, findRolCallback);
    }

    User.findUser(null, null, null, findUserCallback);
}
```

Fíjate que aunque hemos cambiado la estructura del código, el funcionamiento no ha cambiado. Cada función sigue teniendo la llamada a la siguiente anidada en su callback. Simplemente hemos aplanado el código. Aún así, si añadimos más llamadas a BD al final acabaríamos en la misma situación.

Dicho esto, veo que estás utilizando promesas tanto en db.js, como en la implementación de Rol y User. ¿Hay algún motivo para no extender su uso a la función getUsers?

Por ejemplo, si modificásemos findRol de la siguiente manera:

```
// callback es opcional
// si es proporcionado será usado,
// en caso contrario se devolverá una promesa
function findRol (rolId = null, active = null, callback) {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.sendRequest((cp) => {
            new sql.Request(cp)
            .input('rolid', rolId)
            .input('active', active)
            .execute('crmFindRol')
            .then(recordSet => resolve(recordSet))
            .catch(err => reject(err));
        });
    });

    // si no se ha proporcionado callback devolvemos la promesa
    if (!callback) {
        return promise;
    }

    // capturamos el resultado de la promesa y llamámos al callback 
    promise
    .then(result => callback(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

El usuario de la función puede decidir si quiere utilizar promesas o callbacks.

Si usásemos promesas, en la función **getUsers** podríamos hacer lo siguiente (suponiendo que hemos modificado **findUser** de una forma similar):

```
function getUsers (req, res) {
   // Como no pasamos callback ambas funciones
   // devuelven una promesa.
   // Las guardamos en una array.
   const loadDataPromises = [
       User.findUser(null, null, null),
       Rol.findRol(null, null)
   ];

   // Esperamos a que todas las promesas hayan sido resueltas
   Promise.all(loadDataPromises)
   .then((results) => {
       // results contiene los resultados de las promesas
       // de la array loadDataPromises en el mismo orden
       const users = results[0][0];
       const roles = results[1][0];

       res.status(200).render('users', { users, roles });
   })
   // El problema de este método es que si falla una
   // sola promesa saltamos al catch directamente.
   // En este caso diría que es un comportamiento
   // adecuado, pero no siempre lo será.
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Como puedes ver en vez de tener un callback para cada función simplemente vamos añadiendo promesas a la array **loadDataPromises**, esperamos a que todas terminen y obtenemos los resultados con **Promise.all(loadDataPromises)**. De esta manera el código nunca se anidará más de lo que ya está, aunque hagamos centenares de requests a BD.

Las promesas dan mucho juego, pero al igual que los callbacks tienen sus propios peligros. Si vas a desarrollar seriamente código en Node.js te aconsejo que eches un vistazo a su funcionamiento.